# uninitialized constant Gem::UserInteraction (NameError) on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

So I am trying to run grunt on Mac OS X
However, whenever I run it, it always gives me this error. In fact, whenever I try to do anything involving ruby, it gives me this error, even something like gem -v

I checked around google and they said to include a line in /usr/bin/gems but I found that it was already included on line 9

```
  8 require 'rubygems'
  9 require 'rubygems/gem_runner'
 10 require 'rubygems/exceptions'
```

it points to a config.rb file in my Library directory, at this line in particular:

```
 39   include Gem::UserInteraction
```

what can be done to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what the cause is, but I think a recent gem update broke it for me (since some rubygems versions shipped with issues: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/UPGRADING.rdoc). It seems that the config_file in rubygems is messed up, and can't include UserInteraction gem.

What fixed it for me was manually downloading and installing the latest rubygems (v2.1.11) from http://rubygems.org/pages/download. Give it a try, might fix your issue as well, while we wait for someone to explain the root cause.

Comment: well, this does seem to fix for now and nothing is missing or broken

Comment: I've tried this, but when I go to the directory and run `ruby setup.rb` I still get the error :(